# How to stop session to save onsaved objects during query execution?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, session

I have problem with session and query execution, please see code below.

```
class A implements Lifecycle{
    public boolean onUpdate(Session session){
        Query test=session.createQuery("select * from Unknown");
        List list=test.list();
        B b=new B();
        session.save(b);
    }
}
class B{
    C c;
    public B(){
        c=new C();
        c.a=new A();
    }
}
class C implements Lifecycle{
    A a;
    public boolean onSave(Session session){
        a.onUpdate(session);
    }
}
```

I modified A object and called onUpdate method.but exception whenever I call method a.onUpdate();

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.test.C
```

I know that above exception due to query execution in onUpdate method. please suggest me is there is way to stop to save unsaved objects during  queries execution. or any other suggestion to above problem is great helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> please suggest me is there is way to stop to save unsaved objects during queries execution

To strictly answer this question, by default Hibernate will indeed flush the session when performing a query so that you don't get stale results. You can change this behavior using a custom `FlushMode` (COMMIT or NEVER). From the documentation:

> #### [10.10. Flushing the Session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-flushing)
>
> Sometimes the Session will execute the
>   SQL statements needed to synchronize
>   the JDBC connection's state with the
>   state of objects held in memory. This
>   process, called flush, occurs by
>   default at the following points:
>
> - before some query executions
> - from `org.hibernate.Transaction.commit()`
> - from `Session.flush()`
>
> The SQL statements are issued in the
>   following order:
>
> - all entity insertions in the same order the corresponding objects were
>     saved using `Session.save()`
> - all entity updates
> - all collection deletions
> - all collection element deletions, updates and insertions
> - all collection insertions
> - all entity deletions in the same order the corresponding objects were
>     deleted using `Session.delete()`
>
> An exception is that objects using
>   native ID generation are inserted when
>   they are saved.
>
> Except when you explicitly `flush()`,
>   there are absolutely no guarantees
>   about when the Session executes the
>   JDBC calls, only the order in which
>   they are executed. However, Hibernate
>   does guarantee that the
>   `Query.list(..)` will never return
>   stale or incorrect data.
>
> **It is possible to change the default
>   behavior so that flush occurs less
>   frequently.** The `FlushMode` class
>   defines three different modes: only
>   flush at commit time when the
>   Hibernate Transaction API is used,
>   flush automatically using the
>   explained routine, or never flush
>   unless `flush()` is called explicitly.
>   The last mode is useful for long
>   running units of work, where a Session
>   is kept open and disconnected for a
>   long time (see [Section 11.3.2,
>   "Extended session and automatic
>   versioning"](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-optimistic-longsession)).
>
> ```
> sess = sf.openSession();
> Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();
> sess.setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT); // allow queries to return stale state
>
> Cat izi = (Cat) sess.load(Cat.class, id);
> izi.setName(iznizi);
>
> // might return stale data
> sess.find("from Cat as cat left outer join cat.kittens kitten");
>
> // change to izi is not flushed!
> ...
> tx.commit(); // flush occurs
> sess.close();
> ```
>
> During flush, an exception might occur
>   (e.g. if a DML operation violates a
>   constraint). Since handling exceptions
>   involves some understanding of
>   Hibernate's transactional behavior, we
>   discuss it in [Chapter 11,
>   Transactions and Concurrency](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html).

But honestly, I'm not sure to understand what you're trying to do (and maybe it's just a sample but your HQL query is not correct).

#### References

- [10.10. Flushing the Session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-flushing)

Comment: Hi Pascal Thivent,

Thanks for answer. 

HQL is sample one actual code is namedQuery its sql query. when I m trying to update A "obj" object and called onUpdate method of "obj"  
somewhere in code.creating B object in that method, 

B has relation with C which will save when B saving. C has A references and executing A "obj1"  onUpdate() in onSave method of C. when "obj1" 
onUpdate method called Query will execute and during query execution objects is going to save, C is not at saved at this time. so execption is occurs.


Plz let me if dont get it

Comment: @kumar I'm not sure it's really important if I get all the details actually, so it doesn't really matters :)